# save unfolded data to separate file

Tags: folding

Within vim you can fold away some data that doesn't pertain to what you're looking for at that moment. So I'd like to save that unfolded data to a separate file and look at it closer, but I don't know the correct/exact combinations to do this.

I know `:folddoopen .:w >> file.ext` will appended the non-folded data to an existing file, so my temporary work around is just `touch file.ext` before opening vi.

`:folddoopen :w > file.ext` won't work as this writes the entire open file to the file and even loops through it over and over and over. Doing this in my case resulted in a 4.5GB file!

I'm using vim-lite on freeBSD: https://www.freshports.org/editors/vim-lite/

By the way, is unfolded the correct term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `!` to force the writing, even if the file doesn't exist:

```
:folddoopen .:w! >> file
```

Comment: That did it! I don't have enough of a reputation to up vote, but I've marked it as the answer.